# Move population of agents to top layer

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I'm creating a population of agents dynamically using java. While doing so I also create several other shapes, which are partly overlaying. I already learned, that it's not possible to change the stacking order of a shape during runtime. This is easily solved by changing the order of creation in the code.

Somehow this doesnt't work for a population of agents.
How I create the agents:

```
WindTurbine WT = add_windTurbines();
WT.setXY(posX,  posY);
```

This population is partly hidden under other shapes. Is there a way to get it to the front?

Here is the model reduced to all necessary parts. The pipes are overlaying the wind turbines in the 2D View. The pipes should be under the turbines. The turbines are created by using replications and by using code in "On startup:" window.

[Model ZIP](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zjOOxwDPDUAiUxeyWq0dkFV-nIDjvbhn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

go to your population in main, click on the shape that represents your agent, right click, and select bring to front.

[image: example with forklift]

If your population is not defined in main because it's an agent type, I think you should create the population and in your flowchart source add agents to custom population (if you are using the Processing Library or discrete events).. not sure if all these steps are necessary, but try it out.

Comment: That sadly didn't work. I'm using a custom population. It seems AnyLogic defines the layer in this code: `@AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  protected static final int _windTurbines_presentation = 10;`

Comment: wait.. you create the shapes during runtime?

Comment: The agents and the shapes are created in the "On startup:" window in the main class.

Comment: Ok... to avoid these problems I usually create the shape graphically and use replications... and then since each replication has an ID, you can set the position as you want... then my solution will work, can you do that instead? Or how are you creating the shapes?

Comment: This question is related to my other question. The amount of needed shapes is unknown until the simulation is started. So (I think) it's necessary to create the shapes with java on startup. Or is it possible to create replications?

Comment: yes, just create a parameter param that defines the number of replications, and in your startup code, you just do param=6; for example and you will get instantaneously 6 replicas of the shape

Comment: Ok I created the wind turbines using replications. But they are still overlayed by pipes. Currently I'm creating the pipes using the pipe-constructor `new Pipe();`. Maybe there is a better way to create pipes? They are needed for the visualization.

Comment: i don't know... I would have to check your model

Comment: I added the model file to my question. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: i see now... it's impossible to do it like this.. since the last things you create are the ones that stay on the top in 2D... you can maybe solve it by creating the pipes in the form of an agent.. but you would have to try

Comment: Ok thanks! If I create the pipes as an agent I loose the possibility to change the direction of the pipe. I solved it by inserting a wind_turbine object into the main window and cloning it in the code.